# perl Thread::Queue not dequeueing all items

Tags: multithreading, perl

I'm using perl's [Thread::Queue](https://metacpan.org/module/Thread::Queue) module to keep a pool of threads busy downloading urls for a simple crawler I am working on. Using `Thread::Queue`, I enqueue a list of hash references (360, to be exact), where each hash holds information about the individual url:

```
#set up thread queue
my $THREADS=30; # Number of threads
my $url_q = Thread::Queue->new(); # Work to do
my $url_arr = urls();

my $count = 0;
for(@$url_arr) { 
    print "ENQUEUEING $_->{'url'}\n";
    $url_q->enqueue($_);
    $count++;
}

print "COUNT $count\n";
print "QUEUE COUNT " . $url_q->pending() . "\n";

threads->create( sub { 
            while(my $url_h = $url_q->dequeue()) { 
                print "url: $url_h->{'url'}\n\n";
                print "PENDING: " . $url_q->pending() . "\n";
                process_url($url_h);
            }
        }) for (1..$THREADS);   

$url_q->end;
print "WAITING\n";
$_->join() for threads->list;
print "DONE WAITING\n";
```

The problem is that I see all 360 urls be enqueued, but then I only ever see the pending number drop down to around 260, meaning that only about 100 really get evaluated and 260 never do? Is there something wrong I'm doing with Thread::Queue? Thanks!

Comment: What happens after when it gets down to 260 (exits or stops working)?

Comment: This is inside of a loop that just keeps going, so it moves on to the next iteration of the loop and starts working on the next 360 urls.

Comment: Web requests can be asynchronous, you don't need threads.

Comment: That means the threads exited, so either `$url_h` was false or a thread died. Start by finding out which (by using `eval { }`).

Comment: @ikegami, where in the code should I place the `eval { }`?

Comment: Around `process_url` should be good enough.

Comment: Its possible you queued a value which is false (0, empty string, undef) causing the loop to terminate and the thread to exit.

Answer (score 0):

You're sure you do not see any errors?  When I run your code, I see "Can't locate object method "end" via package "Thread::Queue"".  Looking at Thread::Queue's documentation, I do not see any mention of an end function, so perhaps this is a mistake in your code.  In my tests, the "PENDING" counter will stop whenever $url_q->end is called, which varies with how fast your computer is, its current load, and how it schedules the threads.  It could be that on your box, this happens at roughly 260.